# Changing Content on screen Size

Tags: css, html

I want to change my content inside the header tags when my screen's width value is lower then 500px. So I write this code.

```
<header>
        <table style="width:100%" class="deneme">
            <tr>
                <td id="baslik" class="logo" width="53%">Some Text Here</td>
                <td width="23%"></td>
                <td><img src="bannerpic.png" height="115px" width="170px"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</header>
```

and I also write this to my class page

```
@media screen and (max-width:  500px) {
    .deneme{
        background-image: url(bannerpic.png);
    }
}
```

When I use background-color: red for an example it work well. It's actually working this way but the problem is I want to clean the header and show ONLY the bannerpic when my width value is lower then 500 instead of that when I use the codes I write up here it showes me something like this

http://puu.sh/swfNa/16cb398a98.jpg

all I want it if my width value is lower then 500 show ONLY the image no text :)

Comment: I'm confused.. so you want the banner image for background when screen size is less then 500px without class logo and the img tag ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set table contents to `display: none`, so table will not have `width` and `height`, you can hide table contents by using `opacity: 0` or `visibility:hidden`, otherwise you need to set a width or height for your table.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .deneme {
    background-image: url("http://puu.sh/swfNa/16cb398a98.jpg");
  }
  .deneme tr {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <table style="width:100%" class="deneme">
    <tr>
      <td id="baslik" class="logo" width="53%">Some Text Here</td>
      <td width="23%"></td>
      <td>
        <img src="bannerpic.png" height="115px" width="170px">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</header>
```

Comment: Didn't worked I still get this when I lower my width 

http://puu.sh/swmc5/1d321166c1.jpg

Comment: http://puu.sh/swmmD/05809cde4a.jpg this is the last situation :D The text is gone but the image on the right side is still there :/

Comment: Thanks for solution! Just realized the image is repeating so I changed the code like this

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .deneme {
        background-image: url(bannerpic.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .deneme tr {
        opacity: 0;

    }
}

and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping :)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .deneme {
        background-image: url(bannerpic.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .deneme tr {
        opacity: 0;

}
}
```

This code worked very well :)

Answer (score -1):

use CSS Selectors

(pseudo-class .not(){}[:not() - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

so for your code.

`@media screen and (max-width:  500px) {
    .deneme td :not(class for td's img here.){
        display:none;
    }
}`

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it right but I did this

@media screen and (max-width:  500px) {
    .deneme td :not(bannerpic.png){
        display:none;
}
}
but didnt worked :/ Sorry I'm soo new on HTML :/ trying to learn

Comment: You need a class not the image link, so put a class on td and use it in the selector `:not( HERE)`

Comment: Found the solution :) Thanks for helping :)